# Unable to install qemu?

Tags: command-line, system-installation, software-installation, qemu, debugging

I used the following command:

```
sudo apt install libexpect-perl qemu-system-x86 qemu-utils
```

But, I received the following errors:

```
Err:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 ovmf all 0~20181115.85588389-3+deb10u2
  404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.210.132 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/e/edk2/ovmf_0~20181115.85588389-3+deb10u2_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.210.132 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I tried running `apt-get update`, but I received the following errors:

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
```

Comment: Wasn't sure if it's considered software or system installation. Probably considered software-installation

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.